# TorBrowser installer can't be opened

Tags: mac, tor-install

I am running an iMac OS 10.15 (Catalina) and tried to install TorBrowser. I successfully downloaded the .dmg, but when I tried to load it I received an error message "updater can't be opened because Apple cannot check it for maliciious software"
Please advise.
Thank you
/gh

Answer (score 0):

This really has nothing to do with Tor Browser and is a general Mac issue. I don't use Macs but I googled this issue and found the fix [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491).

The summary is that you need to go into your security settings and tell your Mac to open it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

@JSEvans is right on the money .

Open `System Preferences` > `Security & Privacy` > `General`

There should be an option to `allow` the installer to proceed at the bottom of that page.  Click the lock in the bottom left, enter your password, and click `allow`.

**Note:** Be sure to go to system preferences immediately after you get the error message - if you wait too long the aforementioned "allow" option will disappear.

plz upvote so I can make this a comment in the future! :D thx